# Getting random value in php where there must be an exact amount

Tags: php

I have a problem where I need random values in php. I got all that working. But when I need, let's say, 10 random values, I need 8 of them to be at least a certain integer. How can I achieve this?
Kind regards,
Leon

```
<?php
$vertices = $_POST["vertices"];
echo "Vertices: $vertices <br>";
$edges = $_POST["edges"];
echo "Edges: $edges <br>";
$length = $_POST["length"];
echo "Length: $length <br><br>";

$temp1 = $edges;

for($x = 0; $x < $vertices; $x++){
for($i = 0; $i < $x; $i++){
    echo "_   ";
}
for($y = $x; $y < $vertices; $y++){

    $value = rand(0,1);
    if($x == $y){ 
        echo "0   ";
    } else {
        if($value == 1 && $temp1 > 0){
            echo "1   ";
            $temp1--;
        } else {
            echo "0   ";
        }
    }
}
echo "<br>";
}
?>  
<html>
</font>
</html>
```

This will output something like this:

```
Vertices: 5 
Edges: 8 
Length: 4 

0 0 1 0 1 
_ 0 0 1 0 
_ _ 0 1 0 
_ _ _ 0 1 
_ _ _ _ 0
```

However, I need to have exactly 8 1's on the upper half of the matrix. I don't know how to achieve it, because now it will do a random number under 8.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: There's an option for a "min" and "max" when generating a random number: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

Comment: well - you generate your ten integers, check if eight of them are at least a certain integer.. and if they aren't, start over.

Comment: That's not 10 random values: That's 2 random values and 8 values randomly selected from a specific collection.

Comment: Generate a couple of random numbers and just assign 3 (random because you got it off some bloke on the Internet just now) for the rest `for($i=0;$i<8;$i++) { $certainInteger[] = 3; }` : http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25

Comment: You're solving the problem the wrong way. If you know the number of edges you need to create then generate 2 random endpoints for each edge and put it between those 2 vertices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take another approach:

- There are `$vertices * ($vertices - 1) / 2` positions you need to fill (10).
- There should be `$edges` times `1`'s and the rest `0`'s (8 and 2).
- You can fill an array with 8 `1`'s and 2 `0`'s.
- Shuffle the array.
- Loop over your matrix and pop an element of the array for every position you need to fill.

Comment: But the variables (like 10, 8) can change. How do you make an array that would work with that? And how do I shuffle an array?

Comment: I think this might actually work, thanks man! I have an shuffled array now

Comment: I was just going to say that you can use `array_fill` to generate 2 arrays with 0's and 1's and merge them. `shuffle()` the result and done :-)